# Manage memory for creating image view at run time in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have added image view in to textview using beizer path.I am adding that text view into table cell so for many cells many image views will be created which results to creating more objects.So i want to know how can i resolve this issue so that memory will not increase at run time.

```
UIBezierPath * imgRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
cell.tv_post.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[imgRect];
UIImageView *img_view =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
img_view.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"h_like.png"];
[cell.tv_post addSubview:img_view];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom UITableviewCell class with an img_view property. In awakeFromNib you can do something like this:

```css
if (!self.img_view) {
  self.img_view = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0,  100.0, 100.0)];
  self.img_view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"h_like.png"];
  [self addSubView: self.img_View];
}
```